# VT-X prevents boot

Tags: boot, bios, vt-x

this is what happened. 
I was trying to run virtual box on my computer, but it gave me the error message, that I needed to activate VT-X. So, I booted into the bios and set the option for Intel Virtualisation Technology to enabled.

I hit F10 and enter, and my computer went out. And that was pretty much it. It went out, except for diode on the mainboard and sometimes a short flash of an LED on the front together with a quarter turn of the CPU fan when I try to turn my computer on.

I am using a ASUS P8B75 MLX Mainboard. Here's the official documentation link.
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8B75-M_LX_PLUS/E7986_P8B75-M_LX_Plus.pdf?_ga=1.37398308.502756120.1435032157

What I did so far, I removed the CMOS battery, first for 15 minutes, then for a few hours, out of desperation.

I just now found out about the Clear RTC jumper, which didn't lead to success either.

So, I have two questions:

1. Pragmatically: Do I still have any options left?
2. Curiously: How did I mess up my system. And why?

Would be nice if one of you could provide an answer.

Comment: What processor?

Comment: I can't say. I don't have any documentation left after a few moves and I can't remember which one it is. And it doesn't appear as if it is marked.